# Adding random number not in every tilmestep when using numerical integration

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

How can I add a "random factor" only in every second integration step?
Because maybe I don't want to add the Random all the time - for example I Want to add it in time steps = 0.004 or maybe 0.008.

```
dt = 0.002;
end_1 = 2.0;
time = 0:dt:end_1;

Matrix = zeros(10,length(time);
Matrix(:,0.5/dt:0.6/dt) = repmat(...);
Random = randn(10,length(time);
Matrix = Matrix + Random;
```

what is the best way to add Random in a different tilmestep than dt?

This dt = 0.002 will later serve as an integration step for solving a differential equation where matrix occurs - now, however, I would like to add the random component in, for example, coarser time steps (every 2nd ... or possibly only every 10th step).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create an empty matrix `Random = zeros(10, length(time))` and then populate it with random values for specific parts of it only.
For example, if you want to populate it every i-th step, you could do:

```
Random = zeros(10, length(time));
Random(:, 1:i:length(time)) = randn();
```

Just pay attention to wether `length(time)` is divisible or not by your coarser step size.